# Images won't appear on slideshow unleass i click on the dots

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I'm creating a simple slideshow for my college project and while it's working fine the images won't appear on the slideshow at first only the dots and arrows. instead I have to click on the arrows or dots in order for them to show up. This happen everytime I load the page or refresh and i can't figure out why. can someone give me a hand.
Here's my javascript

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("image-container");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

and my CSS

```css
.slide-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto
}

.image-container {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
```

and HTML

```html
<body>
  <div class="slide-container">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="imag1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="image2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="image3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Everything seems fine, check out my live codepen: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/mdVrmKg

Comment: Testing on @Alessio CodePen with 3 different browsers everything seems to work fine. Maybe you could create your own CodePen to see if you can duplicate the issue?